# How to make firm cheescake?

Tags: baking, cheesecake

My family appreciated very firm New York style cheesecake. How does one make it firm, almost the consistency of fork cutting a banana? I was thinking less or no sour cream and more eggs.

Comment: Less that what, exactly? Also if you want a New York style cheesecake why not look for a New York style cheesecake recipe instead of trying to modify one you already have?

Comment: Without an existing recipe we will have a hard time suggesting modifications :) can you [edit] to give some more details about what you typically cook?

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a no bake cheesecake, as I usually do, make sure you use full fat ingredients as they will help it firm up. You can also add gelatin to make it firmer